# Syntax with SQL script replacing date value with null

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, case

I need to print a blank instead of the `1900-01-01` SQL default. I have a case when statement written and tried to insert it into our stored procedure. When I insert it, it throws a bunch of errors.

Where should the `case when` statement be placed within the stored procedure to yield the results we're looking for? Or is there some other mistake?

If there is a cleaner way to do this, I'm open to that too.

```
SELECT
    tsd.PACOSTCATID, cc.PACOSTCATNME,convert(varchar(10),MAX(padt),101) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(10),MAX(PAexptdate),101) DateRange,tsh.EMPLOYID,TSD.PAQtyQ
    tsd.padt, 
    case when convert(date, padt) = '1900-01-01'
    then ''
    ELSE convert(varchar(10),MAX(padt),101) +''+
    CONVERT (CHAR(8), padt, 120)
    END,

    tsd.PAexptdate,
    case when convert (date, PAexptdate) = '1900-01-01'
    then ''
    ELSE convert(varchar(10), PAexptdate,101)+''+
    convert (CHAR(8),paexptdate, 120)
    END
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
USE 
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[dd_PA01201_SEL]    Script Date: 11/03/2015 14:28:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[dd_PA01201_SEL]

--  dd_PA01201_SEL 'sa'

@UserName varchar(30)
AS
select PAprojid, PABEndDate, pm.PAPROJNUMBER, e2.Extender_Record_ID, pm.CUSTNMBR,

        isnull(e1Client.STRGA255,'') as Client, 
        isnull(e1Union.STRGA255,'') as UnionName,
        pm.PAprjclsid, pm.PAprojname, 
        isnull(e3UsageFrom.DATE1,'') as UsageFrom , 
        isnull(e3UsageTo.DATE1,'') as UsageTo, 
        isnull(e3HoldFrom.DATE1,'') as HoldFrom, 
        isnull(e3HoldTo.DATE1,'') as HoldTo,
        isnull(e1ProductionCo.STRGA255, '') as ProductionCo,
        isnull(e2Signatory.STRGA255,'') as Signatory,
        isnull(ub.DateRange, '') as DateRange,
        isnull(ub.PACOSTCATNME,'') as PACOSTCATNME,
        isnull(ub.EMPLOYID,'') as EMPLOYID,
        100 * isnull(ub.PAQtyQ,0) as PAQtyQ
from UPR40200EXT ux
        join PA01201 pm on pm.PAPROJNUMBER = ux.projectnumber --Project Master
        left join EXT01100 e0 on e0.Extender_Window_ID = 'PROJECT_DETAILS' and e0.Extender_Key_Values_1 = pm.PAprojid --Extender Header
        left join EXT01100 e2 on e2.Extender_Window_ID = 'PROJ_SIGNATORY' and e2.Extender_Key_Values_1 = pm.CUSTNMBR --Extender Header
        left join EXT01101 e1Client on e1Client.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e1Client.Field_ID = 1290 --Extender client line
        left join EXT01101 e1Union on e1Union.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e1Union.Field_ID = 1299 --Extender union line
        left join EXT01102 e3UsageFrom on e3UsageFrom.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e3UsageFrom.Field_ID = 1269 --Extender usage from line
        left join EXT01102 e3UsageTo on e3UsageTo.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e3UsageTo.Field_ID = 1270 --Extender usage to line
        left join EXT01102 e3HoldFrom on e3HoldFrom.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e3HoldFrom.Field_ID = 1272 --Extender hold from line                          
        left join EXT01102 e3HoldTo on e3HoldTo.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e3HoldTo.Field_ID = 1274 --Extender hold to line
        left join EXT01101 e1ProductionCo on e1ProductionCo.Extender_Record_ID = e0.Extender_Record_ID and e1ProductionCo.Field_ID = 1290 --Extender ProductionCo line
        left join EXT01101 e2Signatory on e2Signatory.Extender_Record_ID = e2.Extender_Record_ID and e2Signatory.Field_ID = 1296 --Extender signatory line

              --THIS CAUSES THE STORED PROC TO RETURN ONE LINE FOR EACH PAYCODE
        left join (
              SELECT
                          tsd.PACOSTCATID, cc.PACOSTCATNME, tsh.EMPLOYID,TSD.PAQtyQ, 
                          convert(varchar(10),MAX(padt),101) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(10),MAX(PAexptdate),101) DateRange 
                    from UPR10301  ub
                          join PA30100 tsh on tsh.BACHNUMB = ub.BACHNUMB
                          join PA30101 tsd on tsd.PATSNO = tsh.PATSNO
                          join PA01001 cc on cc.PACOSTCATID = tsd.PACOSTCATID
                    where ub.MKDBYUSR = @UserName
                          and ub.UPRBCHMK = 1
                    group by ub.BACHNUMB,tsd.PACOSTCATID,cc.PACOSTCATNME, tsh.EMPLOYID,TSD.PAQtyQ
              ) ub on 1=1

--select * from EXT01100 where Extender_Window_ID = 'PROJ_SIGNATORY ' and Extender_Key_Values_1 = 'anot0001'

--select * from EXT01101 where Extender_Record_ID = 5194

--select * from pa01201

-- update UPR40200EXT set ProjectNumber = 'ALLI2C40094    '
```

Comment: Please fix up that formatting, it's pretty hard to read. You can get code style formatting by prepending 4 spaces.

Comment: @davejagoda is right. Your post was really awful. You can hardly ask for time of others to help you, if you didn't even dedicate your time to make a good question. Please do it yourself next time. Also you're writing about some errors, but you didn't post them in your question, even though it's one of the most important information. You can't fix an error you don't know.

Comment: Whats the error? undertake some basic troubleshooting and test each branch of your case statement individually to find out which one is throwing the error

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I know the formatting was awful, I just wasn't sure how to fix it. Obviously I am new to this - learning and struggling here. But thanks to those who were helpful. I'll try these suggestions and post the error if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using CASE statement is correct. The problem is not where or how you are using it. The problem is that you have a GROUPBY clause and within your CASE statements you are using columns that are not part of the grouping and are not aggregated.

```
SELECT
    tsd.PACOSTCATID
    ,cc.PACOSTCATNME
    ,convert(varchar(10),MAX(tsd.padt),101) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(10),MAX(PAexptdate),101) DateRange
    ,tsh.EMPLOYID
    ,TSD.PAQtyQ
    ,MAX(tsd.padt)
    ,case when convert(date, MAX(tsd.padt)) = '1900-01-01' then ''
          ELSE convert(varchar(10),MAX(tsd.padt),101) +''+ CONVERT (CHAR(8), MAX(tsd.padt), 120)
     END
    ,MAX(tsd.PAexptdate)
    ,case when convert (date, MAX(tsd.PAexptdate)) = '1900-01-01' then ''
          ELSE convert(varchar(10), MAX(tsd.PAexptdate),101)+''+ convert (CHAR(8),MAX(tsd.PAexptdate), 120)
     END
```

If you notice, I have used MAX() for tsd.padt and tsd.paexptdate.

Comment: This makes sense - thank you. I'll try to fix it based on your feedback.